# How can I catch an exception thrown from inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, frameset-iframe

How can I catch an exception thrown inside my iframe?

Here is my code:

Parent:

```
        iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.src = "../a.aspx";
        iframe.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

and the code inside a.aspx:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            GenerateKey();
            //This function throws an exception, and I want to catch it in the parent window (javascript)
    }
```

I want to catch the exception in the page that opens the iframe and show an alert box.
I tried iframe.contentWindow.onerror, but it didn't work.

Thanks for the help,

Inbal.

Comment: Correct the exception error - not try to find solution to catch it.

Comment: @Aristos - I want to display an error to the user, but I want to do that inside the parent page. This is the "Correction".

Comment: when you have the exception (capture it) : render a javascript code that show a message on the parent. There is no other way, the parent page is not running when your iframe throw the exception.

Comment: I tried this inside the iframe server side:
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", "parent.test();", true);

but it didn't work.
Do you have any suggestion why? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Cross origin may disallow you to control iframe. 
Inside your iframe page, you can catch its exception and call parent function to display it.

```
try{
//something
}catch(e){
   window.top.some_public_function(e);
   //window.parent.some_public_function(e) is also work
}
```

Comment: How to deal with exceptions thrown asynchronously?

Comment: @AlexPashkov can you be more specific? Example? Better just create a question